# Is every geodesic curve in an algebraic variety an algebraic set

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry

Let $V$ be a non-singular algebraic variety. Hence $V$ is an analytic manifold.

I wonder if every geodesic curve in $V$ is an algebraic set?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by geodesic? And if you're working with a $\Bbb C$-algebraic variety, how could a real curve be an algebraic set?

Comment: Geodesic in the sense of Riemannian geometry, since every analytic manifold is a Riemmanian manifold.

Comment: If you mean in the sense of Riemannian geometry, what is the natural Riemannian structure you mean to endow it with? The one associated to the Hermitian metric from the $\Bbb CP^N$ in which it sits, in principle?

Comment: In do Carmo's book (Riemannian Geometry) proposition 210 Chap 1, shows that every differentiable manifold has a Riemannian metric.

Comment: I'm well aware of this fact. But there are uncountably many different Riemannian metrics, very few of which have anything to do with the structure of $V$ as complex manifold. I also remind you that a real submanifold will never be a (complex) algebraic set. Start by looking at geodesics on $\Bbb CP^n$ with the standard Fubini-Study metric. We know precisely what the geodesics are.

Comment: Many hanks for your comments. I am working on optimization problem of an entropy function over an affine algebraic variety over reals. And my question is related with a simplification of a proof.

Answer (score 1):

A geodesic is a 1-dimensional real manifold, and the real dimension of a complex analytic manifold is even.

Comment: I don't see the Question as being about dimensionality.  Rather the OP asks if a geodesic curve of an analytic manifold $V$ is an "algebraic set".  Possibly you are commenting about a mismatch in terminology, but even so it will serve better as a Comment (requesting clarification) than as an Answer.